# Preview all rows of a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to use the print function in R to view all 32 rows of a data frame but no matter what I do, only the first 10 rows are printed.

I have tried:

```
print(df)
```

and

```
print(df, min=32)
```

I have also tried:

```
print.data.frame(df)
```

With some luck but it gives all of the columns too.  I really only need the first 10 columns because the output is too jumbled with all 317 shown.

Below is an example of the output that I am currently getting with just 10 rows.

[image]

Comment: Have you noticed there are several pages to this output? For only 10 columns try `df[,1:10]`

Answer (score 1):

If it is a `tibble`, can set the options with

```
options(tibble.print_max = nrow(df))
print(df)
```